# Computational speed of Fortran code reduces with increase in number of processors

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi

I am running a parallel "Hello World " code in Fortran using the command "mpirun -np 250 ./hello". This prints "Hello world" 250 times along with their ranks from 0 to 249.

The server I am working on has 128 cores and 256 threads. The "nprocs" command gives "128" output on my server.

I have a Fortran code whose computational time is lesser for 128 as compared to 250 processors.

So I have two questions,

1. If "hello world " is printed 250 times along with the ranks, does this mean there 250 cores in my server?
2. Why is the computational time less for 128 as compared to 250? Why didn't increasing the "-np" from 128 to 250 decrease the computational speed?

Comment: If you're printing "Hello world" and a rank, 250 times instead of 128 times then it would seem quite reasonable that it takes longer. You are _increasing_ the amount of work done proportionally to the number of ranks. If that isn't what you are doing we'll need to see more detail of your program. (I'd also suggest that you try to learn more about basics of parallel computing through a good tutorial (etc) - Stack Overflow isn't good for introductory learning.)

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Note that most of the processes do not actually print anything, they just send something into some buffer and just one process prints stuff from that buffer. That process will be quite busy with all that printing from many processes. We cannot say more without seeing your code, please show your actual code.

Comment: @francescalus It's not totally clear but I think the OP is increasing the number of processes from 128 to 250 - so for each process the work done is the same. Thus to zeroth order ignoring anything complicated I would expect it to take the same time assuming it really can support properly 2 threads on each core (very, very rash, I know). In the real world I would expect it to take longer, especially if job launch time is being included.

Comment: @IanBush, I agree with that interpretation. What I meant was that one wouldn't expect speed-up (because amount of work increases at least linearly with rank count). Wallclock could be the same, but as you say realistically wallclock is likely to increase because of things like startup, threading costs, IO being serial.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If "hello world " is printed 250 times along with the ranks, does this mean there 250 cores in my server?

No, it doesn't. You can run `mpirun -np 250 ./hello` on a single CPU core and it will still run due to the magic of time-sharing provided you have enough memory in your server and patience.

> 2. Why is the computational time less for 128 as compared to 250? Why didn't increasing the "-np" from 128 to 250 decrease the computational speed?

Hardware threads make use of the fact that in many cases the CPU pipeline can not be fully utilised by a single thread, so another thread could run simultaneously and "fill in the gaps". That works well in cases where one hardware thread is waiting on a slow operation, e.g., memory access, in which case a second hardware thread can use the ALU or the FPU. This is known as latency hiding.

It doesn't work that well when two hardware threads both need access to a single unit such as the FPU. In that case, there is only more overhead and therefore the computation slows down.

Another reason to have it slower with 250 threads is because hardware threads share the core data and instruction caches, cutting the per thread cache volume effectively in half. This is less of a problem in shared-memory programming where all threads share a single address space, but that is not the case with most (virtually all) MPI implementations where each rank is a separate process with its own address space.

Yet another reason could be memory bandwidth. If your program is reading data from or writing data to outside the CPU, e.g., because it doesn't fit completely in the cache, then more MPI ranks will need higher memory bandwidth, but the CPU memory controller can only provide that much of it. You should try running your program with 64 ranks only - perhaps it'll be even faster.